Stuck Installing `mermaid-filter` with `npm i -g` - Installation Hangs on Deprecated Warnings
I'm trying to install mermaid-filter globally using npm with the command:
npm i -g mermaid-filter

However, the installation gets stuck and doesn't complete. My terminal shows several deprecation warnings and then hangs with a rotating cursor at the end. The last few lines I see are:
npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated q@1.5.1: You or someone you depend on is using Q, the JavaScript Promise library that gave JavaScript developers strong feelings about promises. They can almost certainly migrate to the native JavaScript promise now. Thank you literally everyone for joining me in this bet against the odds. Be excellent to each other.
npm warn deprecated
npm warn deprecated (For a CapTP with native promises, see @endo/eventual-send and @endo/captp)
npm warn deprecated puppeteer@19.11.1: < 22.8.2 is no longer supported
-

After this, nothing happens, and the cursor keeps rotating indefinitely.
Here is a GIF of the terminal behavior for reference:

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Any advice on how to proceed or fix this?

I managed to solve the issue I was having with the installation of mermaid-filter. Here's what worked for me:

Installed yarn via npm:
I installed yarn globally using the following command:
npm list -g yarn


Cleared the PATH environment variables:
I opened a new CMD terminal and temporarily cleared the PATH environment variables with:
set "PATH=C:\Windows\System32\;C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;"


Installed mermaid-filter with yarn:
Then, I successfully installed mermaid-filter using yarn by running:
yarn global add mermaid-filter

I had to run this command a few times until it finally succeeded.



Bonus points for using the filter and compile the PDFs:

Restored the PATH environment variables:
After the installation, I opened a new terminal and restored the PATH environment variables to include the necessary directories:
set "PATH=C:\Windows\System32\;C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\;"


Compiled the Markdown file into PDF:
Finally, I was able to compile my Markdown file into a PDF using pandoc with the following command:
pandoc -F "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\mermaid-filter.cmd" fileName.md -o fileName.pdf --pdf-engine=xelatex -V mainfont="DejaVu Serif"



This approach resolved the issue for me, and I was able to generate my PDF successfully.
P.S. follow up question here.
